# Pathauto alias programmatically?

Tags: path-aliases

My custom module enables my **custom token** that allows me to create user paths from one of 3 fields: user:name, or if exists first name + last name, or if exists pageurl field.

this token really gives me the strings like:

Katherine Resette - if page url field is not filled

Mike Nukle - if page url field is not filled

mybeautypage - if page url field is filled

This custom token is: [user:user_pageurl]

and I use this token in [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) Patterns on User Paths: [user:user_pageurl]

it does not create strings like:

example.com/katherine-resette and

example.com/mike-nukle

it use just this line as it is:

example.com/Katerine Resette

Please help me to fine my code with pathauto alias create ?

the code from my module user_pageurl.module is this:

```
     /**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function user_pageurl_token_info() {

  // Add tokens.
  $user['user_pageurl'] = array(
    'name' => t('Page URL'),
    'description' => t('Defines string for user page address based with priorities 
                        (if filled, 3 - high priority, 1 - low priority) : 1. login, 2.fields First name and Last name, 3. field Page URL'),
  );

  return array(
    'tokens' => array(
      'user' => $user,
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function user_pageurl_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $replacements = array();

 if ($type == 'user') {
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'user_pageurl':
          $user_pageurl = user_pageurl_token_replace($data, $options);
          $replacements[$original] = $sanitize ? check_plain($user_pageurl) : $user_pageurl;

          // pathauto clean
          module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto', 'pathauto');
          $replacements[$original] = pathauto_clean_alias($replacements[$original]);
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  // Return the replacements.
  return $replacements;
}

 /**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 * user_pageurl token might contain 1 of 3 user fields
 * 1: user:name - login
 * 2: first name + last name - if exists any
 * 3: pageurl field - if exists - highest priority
 */
function user_pageurl_token_replace($data, $options) {
  //dpm($options);
  $language = $options['language']->language;

  //high priority pageurl token - user:field_pageurl
  //dpm($data['user']->field_pageurl);
  if (isset($data['user']->field_pageurl[$language][0]['safe_value'])) {
    $pageurl = $data['user']->field_pageurl[$language][0]['safe_value'];

    return $pageurl;
  }

  //medium priority pageurl token - user:field_first_name user:field_last_name
  if (isset($data['user']->field_first_name[$language][0]['safe_value'])) {
    $first_name = $data['user']->field_first_name[$language][0]['safe_value'];
    $pageurl = $first_name;
  }
  if (isset($data['user']->field_last_name[$language][0]['safe_value'])) {
    $last_name = $data['user']->field_last_name[$language][0]['safe_value'];
    $pageurl = $last_name;
  }

  if (isset($first_name) &&  isset($last_name)) $pageurl = $first_name . ' '. $last_name;

  //low priority pageurl token - user:name
  $pageurl=$data['user']->name;

  return $pageurl;
}
```

I do not understand why pathauto takes the string as it is and do not transform it replacing uppercases, spaces and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prepare the string yourself, manually. You can use the `pathauto_cleanstring()` helper function that will remove all characters you wouldn't want in the URL (e.g. spaces).

Here's an example:

```
// The function we need is in the pathauto.inc file.
module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto');
$clean_title = pathauto_cleanstring($string_you_want_to_clear);
```

Hope this is what you were asking about.

Comment: this helped me fine! i think module real name has special function for pathauto transformation. this is why i need only to type real name token and it works. so in my module i need this line as you type. thank you

Comment: You're welcome - glad it helped.